# setContentView(R.layout.main); error when start new project

Tags: android

I'm just starting to develop with android, and a followed a tutorial on google to get everything set up. I'm using eclipse and I have both the android sdk and the eclipse plugin installed, but when I create a new Android Project, I get an error on this line from the start.

my code :-

```
package khalid.app.fm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.R.*;

public class RadioBlancoFMActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: import R from u project.

Answer (score 4):

remove

```
import android.R.*;
```

Don't import android.R.

Comment: try cleaning your project (for eclipse, Project -> Clean...)

Comment: Whats the erorr? R not resolved? And yes. trying Eclipse->Project->Clean as stated above. `R.layout.main` is refering to your own R.

Comment: @TronicZomB - :-  i will do this ( Project -> Clean...) but still error

Comment: @wtsang02 i will do this ( Project -> Clean...) but still error

Comment: What is the error? Or try restart Eclipse. Sometimes it does give false compile errors , but rare.

Comment: What do you see in /res/layout/?.xml What file do you see there?

Comment: @wtsang02 this is code on  /res/layout/?.xml
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: I just the filename. use the file name and replace it with the .main

Comment: @wtsang02 its name `main.xml`

Comment: Remake a new project. Try to run that. see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

As @wtsang02 said, don't import `android.R`. I would just like to add that `android.R` is not the same as when using `R.id` or `R.layout`. `android.R` is referencing resources that are built in to the Android resources themselves. `R` references the resources that you have designed for you application.

Comment: @khalidGFX the next step I think would be to check what Daniel mentioned... usually a clean will fix these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the AndroidManifest has reference to khalid.app.fm package.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the `project -> build automatically` is active